# How google gson library can be used to parse given below json

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this JSON

```
{
    "309":{ "productId":309,  "name":"Heat Gear Polo"},
    "315":{ "productId":310,  "name":"Nike"},
    "410":{ "productId":311,  "name":"Armani"}
}
```

and Sample Model Class is

```
public class Product
{
   private int productId;
   private String name;

   // getter and setter for productId and name fields
}
```

How can I store above json data in Product class? Should I use an array or `ArrayList` for Product Class and how do I it using Google Gson library ?

Comment: I guess the only way you have is to generate from the JSON a Map and then iterate Map

Comment: please provide some sample code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parse the whole JSON string as a `Map<Integer, Product>`, using `TypeToken` to specify the generic type. Here's some working code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JsonTest {
  private static final String JSON = "{" +
    "\"309\":{ \"productId\":309,  \"name\":\"Heat Gear Polo\"}," +
    "\"315\":{ \"productId\":310,  \"name\":\"Nike\"},"+
    "\"410\":{ \"productId\":311,  \"name\":\"Armani\"}"+
  "}";

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Product>>(){}.getType();
    Map<Integer, Product> map = g.fromJson(JSON, type);

    System.out.println(map);
  }

  public static class Product
  {
     private int productId;
     private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("Product [productId=%s, name=%s]", productId, name);
    }     
  }
}
```

Comment: Does Product class need to be "static" ? Can it be singleton ?

Comment: I only made it an inner class to have it fit in one file for my example. You can have it be it's own top level class in it's own file, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = "{\"309\":{ \"productId\":309,  \"name\":\"Heat Gear Polo\"},\"315\":{ \"productId\":310,  \"name\":\"Nike\"},\"410\":{ \"productId\":311,  \"name\":\"Armani\"}}";
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Product>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, Product> myMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        System.out.println(myMap);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```